# Correct naming of lonely (no variable name) splat operator in Ruby multiple assignment expression

Tags: ruby

Every entity in development has it's own name, that help developers to communicate.
The classical `splat operator` in `multiple assignment` in `Ruby` is a common thing.

```
a, *rest, z = %w{a the long road z}
p a # "a"
p z # "z"
p rest # ['the', 'long', 'road']
```

Today I found that it tread as working code by `Ruby`, when I skip a variable name after a `splat operator`. Like this:

```
a, *, z = %w{a the long road z}
p a # "a"
p z # "z"
```

How this **Lonely splat operator in multiple assignment** correctly called?

Comment: Would also be interesting to know where the official documentation for this feature is. The [multiple assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) documentation does not seem to mention it

Comment: since it does not seem to have a name already, i hereby name it "naked splat"

Comment: The documentation on [Array/Hash Argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array-2FHash+Argument) says _"bare *"_ so you might call it a _"bare splat"_.

Comment: The unit test is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5b593e388931490c1e2246d0347c892440167b2c/spec/rubyspec/optional/capi/kernel_spec.rb#L219-L233). I second the nomination for "lonely splat" (enabling us to sing ["`*` is the loneliest splat,..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5ab8BOu4LE).